# Get all venues under one category

Tags: api, foursquare

How to get all venues belonging to one particular venue category?
Let's say I need all the venues in London under the 'Arts & Entertainment' category.
What is the API endpoint for that? What is the maximum venues limit in response?

Comment: welcome to SO! Provide some code for your question: what you tried, etc See also  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Search for Venues - Foursquare Developer 
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/search

You can use `categoryId` parameter to specify category.